# Request.ServerVariables in ASP .NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to clear the values set in request.servervariables in code behind of asp .net. I'm trying the logout module as once I click on logout button I will redirect to logout page and in pageload method I'll clear all the session but clearing session is not clearing the value set in `Request.ServerVariable["User"]`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Clear();
        Session.RemoveAll();
        Session.Abandon();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code :-

> Request.Params.Clear();

if you want to delete servervariables data according to type use this one

> Request.ServerVariables["variableName"].Remove(0);

it will delete all characters from this string